# TypeError: urlopen() got multiple values for keyword argument 'body' while executing tests through Selenium and Python on Kubuntu 14.04

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, urllib3, urlopen

im trying to run a selenium in python on Kubuntu 14.04. 
I get this error message trying with chromedriver or geckodriver, both same error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "vse.py", line 15, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'/root/Desktop/chromedriver')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 75, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 156, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 251, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 318, in execute
    response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 375, in execute
    return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 397, in _request
    resp = self._conn.request(method, url, body=body, headers=headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/request.py", line 79, in request
    **urlopen_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/request.py", line 142, in request_encode_body
    **urlopen_kw)
TypeError: urlopen() got multiple values for keyword argument 'body'
```

---

```
import time
import mapeamentos as map
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from random import randint
import datetime
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'/root/Desktop/chromedriver')
driver.get('http://192.168.1.11:66/webclient/login.html')
```

This error gets fired in:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
```

Ive tried with options, without options, without the hardcoded path ou with the path.

I have no ideia what is happening. thanks everyone.

Answer (score 9):

You can update your `urllib3` using

```
pip install --upgrade --ignore-installed urllib3
```

Comment: Don't forget `pip3` for Python 3.

Answer (score 6):

This error message...

```
TypeError: urlopen() got multiple values for keyword argument 'body'
```

...implies that the *Python Client* faced an error while invoking `urlopen()` internally.

This error is usually caused by an *older version* of `pip` that is installed by your systems *package manager* and can be replaced with a newer version of **pip**.

---

### Solution

Upgrading **`pip`** to the latest version (atleast v**18.0**) will solve your problem.

```
C:\Users\myUser>python -m pip install --upgrade pip
Collecting pip
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5f/25/e52d3f31441505a5f3af41213346e5b6c221c9e086a166f3703d2ddaf940/pip-18.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.3MB)
    100% |¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦| 1.3MB 544kB/s
Installing collected packages: pip
  Found existing installation: pip 10.0.1
    Uninstalling pip-10.0.1:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-10.0.1
Successfully installed pip-18.0
```

---

### References

- [TypeError: urlopen() got multiple values for keyword argument 'body'](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/issues/481)
- [TypeError: urlopen() got multiple values for keyword argument 'body' ON patch_namespaced_deployement](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/issues/214)

Comment: On Xubuntu 14.04.5, even after upgrading pip to v18.1 when I run the command `pip install urllib3` I get still
`Requirement already satisfied: urllib3 in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (1.7.1)`. The library is Not upgraded. See my [new stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53199623/typeerror-urlopen-got-multiple-values-for-keyword-argument-body-while-tryin). So I am still stuck with the problem.