# TypeError: urlopen() got multiple values for keyword argument 'body' while trying Selenium on Xubuntu 14.04.5

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, urllib3

### Environment

```
# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

### GCC

```
gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.5-4ubuntu8~14.04.2) 4.8.5
```

#### Python

```
python --version
Python 2.7.6
```

#### Pip

```
pip --version
pip 18.1 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip (python 2.7)
```

#### urllib3

```
pip list | grep url
urllib3                      1.7.1
```

#### Chromedriver

```
chromedriver --version
ChromeDriver 2.33.506092 (733a02544d189eeb751fe0d7ddca79a0ee28cce4)
```

#### Chromium

```
chromium-browser --version
Chromium 65.0.3325.181 Built on Ubuntu , running on Ubuntu 14.04
```

#### Selenium

```
pip install selenium
Requirement already satisfied: selenium in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (3.141.0)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3 in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from selenium) (1.7.1)
```

#### Chrome driver for linux 64bit install

I tried several version, but all lead to the same **new** problem

```
rm ~/Downloads/chromedriver_linux64.zip \
wget -N http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.26/chromedriver_linux64.zip -P ~/Downloads; \
unzip ~/Downloads/chromedriver_linux64.zip -d ~/Downloads; \
chmod +x ~/Downloads/chromedriver; \
rm /usr/local/share/chromedriver; \
sudo mv -f ~/Downloads/chromedriver /usr/local/share/chromedriver; \
rm /usr/local/bin/chromedriver; \
sudo ln -s /usr/local/share/chromedriver /usr/local/bin/chromedriver; \
rm /usr/bin/chromedriver; \
sudo ln -s /usr/local/share/chromedriver /usr/bin/chromedriver; \
ls -al /usr/bin/chromedriver; \
ls -al /usr/local/bin/chromedriver; \
ls -al /usr/local/share/chromedriver
```

... tried

```
# wget -N http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.21/chromedriver_linux64.zip -P ~/Downloads
# wget -N http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.27/chromedriver_linux64.zip -P ~/Downloads
# wget -N http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.33/chromedriver_linux64.zip -P ~/Downloads
# wget -N http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.43/chromedriver_linux64.zip -P ~/Downloads
# wget -N http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/71.0.3578.33/chromedriver_linux64.zip -P ~/Downloads
```

### Test script `test.py`

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities    
# enable browser logging
d = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
d['loggingPrefs'] = { 'browser':'ALL' }
driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=d)
# load some site
driver.get('http://foo.com')
# print messages
for entry in driver.get_log('browser'):
    print entry
```

### Error

```
python test.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 6, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=d)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 81, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 319, in execute
    response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 374, in execute
    return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 397, in _request
    resp = self._conn.request(method, url, body=body, headers=headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/request.py", line 79, in request
    **urlopen_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/request.py", line 142, in request_encode_body
    **urlopen_kw)
TypeError: urlopen() got multiple values for keyword argument 'body'
```

Followed other threads

[TypeError: urlopen got multiple values for keyword argument 'body' while executing tests through Selenium and Python on Kubuntu 14.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51686224/typeerror-urlopen-got-multiple-values-for-keyword-argument-body-while-execu/51707029)

#### urllib3 version

```
# aptitude show python-urllib3
Package: python-urllib3                  
State: installed
Automatically installed: yes
Version: 1.7.1-1ubuntu4.1
Priority: optional
Section: python
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: all
Uncompressed Size: 201 k
Depends: python:any (< 2.8), python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~), python-six
Recommends: ca-certificates
Description: HTTP library with thread-safe connection pooling for Python
 urllib3 supports features left out of urllib and urllib2 libraries. 

 * Re-use the same socket connection for multiple requests (HTTPConnectionPool and HTTPSConnectionPool) (with optional client-side certificate verification). 
 * File posting (encode_multipart_formdata). 
 * Built-in redirection and retries (optional). 
 * Supports gzip and deflate decoding. 
 * Thread-safe and sanity-safe. 
 * Small and easy to understand codebase perfect for extending and building upon.
Homepage: http://urllib3.readthedocs.org
```

I have another setup with same chromium-browser chromedriver versions and the error doesn't happen. What else could I check?

Any further pointers?

## UPDATE

On the environment where the issue doesn't happen the **pip** version isn't the same.

`pip v1.5.4` instead `pip install --upgrade pip==1.5.4`
Now uninstalling `pip 18.1` and reinstalling my pip packages.

To install back the latest version of `pip` if you want to revert again

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Also noted that on the functioning machine I have a slightly different version of GCC

```
gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) 4.8.4
```

## Resolved

I had to start from a fresh Xubuntu setup and ran

```
sudo pip install -U urllib3
```

Comment: Got exact same issue on same versions.

Comment: upvote the question, see if someone can help. thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Potential solutions:

1- Try upgrading the version o urllib3, seems like the version of urllib3 is old according to: https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/requirements.txt

Make sure the version of urllib3 is 1.16 or more. Here, you can find the setup:
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python-urllib3/1.21.1-1

Ref (another post in SO): [TypeError: urlopen() got multiple values for keyword argument 'body' while executing tests through Selenium and Python on Kubuntu 14.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51686224/typeerror-urlopen-got-multiple-values-for-keyword-argument-body-while-execu)

2- Update the version of python:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/python-3.6
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install python3.6
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.5 1
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.6 2
sudo update-alternatives --config python3
```

Ref: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2017/07/install-python-3-6-1-in-ubuntu-16-04-lts/

Comment: Thank you for your contribution! I have a strong dependency on the version of Python 2.7.6, and I need to stay on Ubuntu 14.04.5 :( `pip install urllib3` I get `Requirement already satisfied: urllib3 in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`. It won't install a newer version.

Comment: Try a different way to upgrade your urllib3 version maybe? u can download the tar.gz from the link in my answer and install manually?

Comment: not 100% sure but reinstalling "requests" might help the Request already satisfied issue as well, via "pip uninstall requests", then "pip install requests". I believe there is a very big chance this issue is related to the version of urllib3 that have been installed

Comment: Apparently can't uninstalled `requests` (owned by OS).

Comment: Yeah on `pip uninstall requests` I get
`Not uninstalling requests at /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages, owned by OS`. What's puzzling is that I do have an older setup where I ran the same install commands and have the same version of `urllib3` but there I don't get the error. I am trying to find what library may have been upgraded. I am not able to update `urllib3` with `pip`

Comment: wait, I was able to update `urllib3` now starting from a fresh install ... wow. Somehow, something was not allowing to perform `pip install -U urllib3`, but with a fresh install it did. (??) Nevermind. Thank you for the support

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183465/discussion-between-zabumba-and-eray-balkanli).

Answer (score 2):

Took some risk and removed urllib 1.7.1 (default one that ships within Ubuntu 14.04). It may depend on your requirements if you want to take risk and uninstall it.

```
sudo apt-get remove python-urllib3
```

followed by

```
sudo pip install -U urllib3
```

This fixed the issue for me.